# BottomSheet disapper after loading image via Glide

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide, bottom-sheet

I want dynamically change `ImageView` content which is in the `BottomSheet`. The problem is when I use `Glide` to load image into my `ImageView` it triggers `requestLayout()` of  itself and as the result - `BottomSheet` is gone. If I comment `Glide` loading code, everithing works just fine. I mean, the `TextView` changes text and `BottomSheet` does not disappear.

How should I deal with image loading?

Here is my code

bottom_sheet_item.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_160sdp"
    style="@style/MinElevationStyle"
    android:background="@color/colorHint"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        tools:text="some text"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/TextSmall"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout


  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.trader.marinentrader.ui.search.searchresults.map.MapWithItemsFragment">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".ui.search.searchresults.SearchResultsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetItem"
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_item" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and exec code

```
 private fun bindItem(item: ItemEntity){
    val imagePath = item.media?.firstOrNull()?.path
    if(imagePath == null){
        imageViewItem.clearGlide()
    }else{
        imageViewItem.load(imagePath)
    }
    textView.text = item.title
}
```

load image via kotlin extension

```
fun ImageView.load(any: Any?, placeholder: Int = 0){
GlideApp
        .with(this)
        .load(any)
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(placeholder)
        .fallback(placeholder)
        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
        .into(this)
}
```

Comment: by _disappear_, do you mean that the bottom sheet collapse back to bottom or just vanishes?

Comment: just vanishes with no animation. And after debugging, I found that bottomSheet.state is still STATE_EXPANDED

Comment: I believe it could be because of your root `<ConstraintLayout\>` of bottom sheet xml, Change it to `<LinearLayout\>` and try

Comment: @SripadRaj still nothing. Have tryed both with LinearLayout and FrameLayout as the root ViewGroup

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087352/android-bottomsheet-doesnt-disappear-normally)

Comment: Have you found the solution??

Comment: @gautamkumar no, i have not. I did my own view with sliding animation like BottomSheet but still it was not a solution because of reimplementing a vehicle